# How to check if network is available on Android and iOS ( Delphi XE5 )

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

- How to check if network is available on Android and iOS?

Comment: this is very raw method. :|
is this the normal way to do it on Android platform?

Comment: It is indeed but cannot think of anything better

Comment: I added the android tag, possibly gives an answer to the question

Comment: can you explain what do you mean with `check if network is available`?

Comment: Generally getting the state if the network interfaces is up and ready, and the network ( internet connectivity ) is available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
unit Network;

interface

function IsConnected: Boolean;

function IsWiFiConnected: Boolean;

function IsMobileConnected: Boolean;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.Helpers, Misc;

type
  JConnectivityManager = interface;
  JNetworkInfo = interface;

  JNetworkInfoClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{E92E86E8-0BDE-4D5F-B44E-3148BD63A14C}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/net/NetworkInfo')]
  JNetworkInfo = interface(JObject)
  ['{6DF61A40-8D17-4E51-8EF2-32CDC81AC372}']
    {Methods}
    function isAvailable: Boolean; cdecl;
    function isConnected: Boolean; cdecl;
    function isConnectedOrConnecting: Boolean; cdecl;
  end;
  TJNetworkInfo = class(TJavaGenericImport<JNetworkInfoClass, JNetworkInfo>) end;

  JConnectivityManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{E03A261F-59A4-4236-8CDF-0068FC6C5FA1}']
    {Property methods}
    function _GetTYPE_WIFI: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetTYPE_WIMAX: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetTYPE_MOBILE: Integer; cdecl;
    {Properties}
    property TYPE_WIFI: Integer read _GetTYPE_WIFI;
    property TYPE_WIMAX: Integer read _GetTYPE_WIMAX;
    property TYPE_MOBILE: Integer read _GetTYPE_MOBILE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/net/ConnectivityManager')]
  JConnectivityManager = interface(JObject)
  ['{1C4C1873-65AE-4722-8EEF-36BBF423C9C5}']
    {Methods}
    function getActiveNetworkInfo: JNetworkInfo; cdecl;
    function getNetworkInfo(networkType: Integer): JNetworkInfo; cdecl;
  end;
  TJConnectivityManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JConnectivityManagerClass, JConnectivityManager>) end;

function GetConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
var
  ConnectivityServiceNative: JObject;
begin
  ConnectivityServiceNative := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if not Assigned(ConnectivityServiceNative) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not locate Connectivity Service');
  Result := TJConnectivityManager.Wrap(
    (ConnectivityServiceNative as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not access Connectivity Manager');
end;

function IsConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  ActiveNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  ActiveNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo;
  Result := Assigned(ActiveNetwork) and ActiveNetwork.isConnected;
end;

function IsWiFiConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  WiFiNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  WiFiNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(TJConnectivityManager.JavaClass.TYPE_WIFI);
  Result := WiFiNetwork.isConnected;
end;

function IsMobileConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  MobileNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  MobileNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(TJConnectivityManager.JavaClass.TYPE_MOBILE);
  Result := MobileNetwork.isConnected;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What about on iOS? (OP asked about Android and iOS). I use the solution described here: http://delphiworlds.com/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5/

Comment: You make a valid point. I was only addressing the Android question. Thanks for the link to an iOS solution.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks a lot to [blong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817399/blong) for solution. For it began to work at Delphi Berlin, I redid the module code. I hope this is useful.

At the RAD 10.1 can be used entirely Androidapi.JNI.Net.pas module. But for the study may be useful to make the proposed functions in a separate module.

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.Network;

interface

function IsConnected: Boolean;
function IsWiFiConnected: Boolean;
function IsMobileConnected: Boolean;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.Helpers;

// type
// JConnectivityManager = interface;
// JNetworkInfo = interface;
//
// JNetworkInfoClass = interface(JObjectClass)
// ['{E92E86E8-0BDE-4D5F-B44E-3148BD63A14C}']
// end;
//
// [JavaSignature('android/net/NetworkInfo')]
// JNetworkInfo = interface(JObject)
// ['{6DF61A40-8D17-4E51-8EF2-32CDC81AC372}']
// { Methods }
// function isAvailable: Boolean; cdecl;
// function IsConnected: Boolean; cdecl;
// function isConnectedOrConnecting: Boolean; cdecl;
// end;
// TJNetworkInfo = class(TJavaGenericImport<JNetworkInfoClass, JNetworkInfo>)
// end;
//
// JConnectivityManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
// ['{E03A261F-59A4-4236-8CDF-0068FC6C5FA1}']
// { Property methods }
// function _GetTYPE_WIFI: Integer; cdecl;
// function _GetTYPE_WIMAX: Integer; cdecl;
// function _GetTYPE_MOBILE: Integer; cdecl;
// { Properties }
// property TYPE_WIFI: Integer read _GetTYPE_WIFI;
// property TYPE_WIMAX: Integer read _GetTYPE_WIMAX;
// property TYPE_MOBILE: Integer read _GetTYPE_MOBILE;
// end;
//
// [JavaSignature('android/net/ConnectivityManager')]
// JConnectivityManager = interface(JObject)
// ['{1C4C1873-65AE-4722-8EEF-36BBF423C9C5}']
// { Methods }
// function getActiveNetworkInfo: JNetworkInfo; cdecl;
// function getNetworkInfo(networkType: Integer): JNetworkInfo; cdecl;
// end;
// TJConnectivityManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JConnectivityManagerClass, JConnectivityManager>)
// end;

function GetConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
var
  ConnectivityServiceNative: JObject;
begin
  ConnectivityServiceNative := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService
    (TJContext.JavaClass.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if not Assigned(ConnectivityServiceNative) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not locate Connectivity Service');
  Result := TJConnectivityManager.Wrap((ConnectivityServiceNative as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not access Connectivity Manager');
end;

function IsConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  ActiveNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  ActiveNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo;
  Result := Assigned(ActiveNetwork) and ActiveNetwork.IsConnected;
end;

function IsWiFiConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  WiFiNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  WiFiNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(TJConnectivityManager.JavaClass.TYPE_WIFI);
  Result := WiFiNetwork.IsConnected;
end;

function IsMobileConnected: Boolean;
var
  ConnectivityManager: JConnectivityManager;
  MobileNetwork: JNetworkInfo;
begin
  ConnectivityManager := GetConnectivityManager;
  MobileNetwork := ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(TJConnectivityManager.JavaClass.TYPE_MOBILE);
  Result := MobileNetwork.IsConnected;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
uses System.Net.HttpClient                     

function CheckInternet: boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
  with THTTPClient.Create do
  try
    try
      Result := Head('http://google.com').StatusCode < 400;
    except
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the source directory in front of me right now but this should help point you in the right direction.

I believe you will be able to redo the below android solution in delphi:
[Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

Edit: This line replicates the first line of that function exactly, just not sure what type is returned. Once you have that the rest of that function should be trivial:

> SharedActivitiyContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.ConnectivityService)

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [fmxexpress](http://www.fmxexpress.com/must-have-check-network-connectivity-state-library-for-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/) site.You typically use IdTCPClient component and check if you can connect to google.com

Comment: Do not use Indy components. Better use native THttpClient from System.Net.HttpClient . It's more stable and work with https on Android 6 without problems and do not need any additional libraries.