# Dim Screen Android Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, screen, firemonkey

Does anyone know how to dim the screen on Delphi Firemonkey for Android? I've been googling around and searching but could only find how to remove the auto dim for android by acquiring a Wakelock ([Delphi XE5 Android. How to use PowerManager.WakeLock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021647/delphi-xe5-android-how-to-use-powermanager-wakelock)).

At best I'd like to achieve two states:
Evening = 20% brightness
Daytime = 100% brightness

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: An embarrassing quick-and-dirty solution - that does not change the screen properties, just the rendered picture - would be using a `TContrastEffect` on the entire form and setting the Brightness to `-0.8`. Since the effect does not affect the form itself, the content itself would have to put onto a `TPanel` and the effect applied on the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865), which has the Java solution, as a guide I rustled up this helper unit that should work in Delphi versions from around XE8 to 10.1 Berlin, which seems to do the trick:

```
unit ScreenBrightnessU;

interface

function GetScreenBrightness: Byte;
procedure SetScreenBrightness(Brightness: Byte);

implementation

uses
  MiscU,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
{$IF RTLVersion >= 31}
  FMX.DialogService,
{$ELSE}
  FMX.Dialogs,
{$ENDIF}
  System.UITypes,
  System.SysUtils,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

function GetScreenBrightness: Byte;
var
  Resolver: JContentResolver;
begin
  Resolver :=
{$IF RTLVersion >= 30}
    TAndroidHelper.ContentResolver;
{$ELSE}
    SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver;
{$ENDIF}
  Result := TJSettings_System.JavaClass.getInt(
    Resolver,
    TJSettings_System.JavaClass.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
end;

procedure SetScreenBrightness(Brightness: Byte);
var
  Resolver: JContentResolver;
  AttainedBrightness: Single;
  LayoutParams: JWindowManager_LayoutParams;
  Window: JWindow;
begin
  if not HasPermission('android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS') then
{$IF RTLVersion >= 31}
    TDialogService.MessageDialog('App does not have the WRITE_SETTINGS permission', TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel], TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel, 0, nil)
{$ELSE}
    MessageDlg('App does not have the WRITE_SETTINGS permission', TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel], 0)
{$ENDIF}
  else
  begin
{$IF RTLVersion >= 30}
    Resolver := TAndroidHelper.ContentResolver;
{$ELSE}
    Resolver := SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver;
{$ENDIF}
    // This will set the manual mode (set the automatic mode off)
    TJSettings_System.JavaClass.putInt(
      Resolver,
      TJSettings_System.JavaClass.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
      TJSettings_System.JavaClass.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    // This will set the required brightness
    TJSettings_System.JavaClass.putInt(
      Resolver,
      TJSettings_System.JavaClass.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
      Brightness);
    try
      AttainedBrightness := GetScreenBrightness;
      CallInUIThread(
        procedure
        begin
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 30}
          Window := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow;
  {$ELSE}
          Window := SharedActivity.getWindow;
  {$ENDIF}
          LayoutParams := Window.getAttributes;
          LayoutParams.screenBrightness := AttainedBrightness / 255;
          Window.setAttributes(LayoutParams);
        end);
    except
      // ONOES!!!!
      // <sweeps issue under the carpet>
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

You'll note that the code does permission checking via the helper unit below. This is not vital so long as you ensure you have the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission set in your project for all the Android build configurations.

```
unit MiscU;

interface

function HasPermission(const Permission: string): Boolean;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

function HasPermission(const Permission: string): Boolean;
begin
  //Permissions listed at http://d.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
{$IF RTLVersion >= 30}
  Result := TAndroidHelper.Context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(
{$ELSE}
  Result := SharedActivityContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(
{$ENDIF}
    StringToJString(Permission)) =
    TJPackageManager.JavaClass.PERMISSION_GRANTED
end;

end.
```

Comment: This works like a charm, many thanks. When I tried to do this I must have forgotten the WRITE_SETTINGS!