# Determine if Location Service is on

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How to determine if Location service On/Off in firemonkey application?

I am aware about the article: [How to check if network is available on Android ( Delphi XE5 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888345/how-to-check-if-network-is-available-on-android-delphi-xe5). I am not sure that helps me to detect if Location Service is on or off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine if the location services is On/Off, you must check if the GPS and Network Location services are activated, for this you must use the [`isProviderEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String) method of the [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) class, In Delphi this class is defined in the `Androidapi.JNI.Location` unit.

Check this sample

```
uses
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

{$R *.fmx}       

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  locationManager : JLocationManager;
begin
  locationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(
    ((SharedActivity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE)) 
    as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

  if locationManager.isProviderEnabled(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER) then
   ;   //do something   

  if locationManager.isProviderEnabled(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.NETWORK_PROVIDER) then 
   ;   //do something  else   

end;
```