# implementing addDefaultNetworkActiveListener in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, c++builder, delphi-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Using the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888345/how-to-check-if-network-is-available-on-android-and-ios-delphi-xe5), I was able to get the status of network. But I also need to implement the event for when the status changes. I know I have to use the [addDefaultNetworkActiveListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#addDefaultNetworkActiveListener(android.net.ConnectivityManager.OnNetworkActiveListener)) procedure, but I am having trouble with the interface of `OnNetworkActiveListener`. Does anyone know what the interface for `OnNetworkActiveListener` looks like?

Thank you
Sam

Comment: You've seen https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.OnNetworkActiveListener.html?

Comment: @MartynA Yes, I meant the Delphi interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to construct something like this:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.Net;

type
  TNetworkActiveListener = class(TJavaLocal, JConnectivityManager_OnNetworkActiveListener)
  public
    procedure onNetworkActive; cdecl;
  end;
```

Then declare a variable:

```
  FNetworkActiveListener: TNetworkActiveListener;
```

create it and add it:

```
  FNetworkActiveListener := TNetworkActiveListener.Create;
  // Use the code from the other answer for GetConnectivityManager
  GetConnectivityManager.addDefaultNetworkActiveListener(FNetworkActiveListener);
```

Comment: `FNetworkActiveListener` should be declared as `JConnectivityManager_OnNetworkActiveListener` instead, since that is what `addDefaultNetworkActiveListener()` is expecting.  And just like in Win32, you shouldn't mix object references and interface references (even if the reference counting issue is not a problem in mobile).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not saying that it isn't a problem, however you might like to report that as such for all the instances that EMBT do the same in the RTL/FMX units